# PHP "for loop" <th> tag, from MySQL database to HTML Table

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, html-table

I make a "HTML Table" from a "MySQL database". 
I was able to do a "php loop for" to retrieve the "cell tag `<td>`",  but how can i do a "php loop for" to retrieve the "header tag `<th>`" ? Thanks.

Here is my code :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Landscapes";
$queryResult = $conn->query($query);

echo "<table>";

while ($queryRow = $queryResult->fetch_row()) {
    echo "<tr>";
        for($i = 0; $i < $queryResult->field_count; $i++){
        echo "<td>$queryRow[$i]</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. I would love to assist but feel some information is missing. Where are you expecting to get the header row from? Is it from a different query? Are you using the database table column names?

Comment: Hi. 1- The "header row" is just after the <table> tag. 2- No, it's the same query. 3-Yes, ilt's the "database table column name".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fetch_assoc()` instead of `fetch_row()`. It will return an associative array whose keys are the column names.

When the first row of results you can then print the column headers.

```
$firstRow = true;
while ($queryRow = $queryResult->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($firstRow) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach (array_keys($queryRow) as $name)) {
            echo "<th>$name</th>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        $firstRow = false;
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($queryRow as $value){
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to stack overflow!

You need a way to retrieve all the data from database with the column names.
[PDO::query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) method returns a [PDO::Statement](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdostatement.php) so you can fetch all data with [PDO::fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) and passing the [PDO::FETCH_ASSOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchall-parameters) as argument to retrieve the data as an associative array from the database and remove the `while` loop from your code.

So once with an array of data you can manipulate it with [array functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) and than your code will look like:

```php
$stmt = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM Landscapes');
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$headers    = sprintf('<thead><tr><th>%s</th></tr></thead>', join('</th><th>', array_keys($result[0])));
$content    = '';

foreach ($result as $result) {
   $content .= sprintf('<tr><td>%s</td></tr>', join('</td><td>', array_values($result)));
}

printf('<table border="1">%s%s</table>', $headers, $content);
```

**Related links:**

- PHP PDO documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
- PHP Array functions https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php
- PHP strings functions https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: Very interessant. Thanks for this links.